# datatables fn.Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables plugin but I have a problem with the search.
When I do look like this:

```
$("#productomostrar").change(function() {
   tablalistaproductos.fnFilter($(this).val(),null,false,false,false,false);
});
```

to not be displayed in the search box on the table. But when I try to use the search box does not respect me for the previous search. Any help? I do not want to use ajax because all data by loading the page and I have them loaded. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/change/) - the first parameter of the function is the event object - so `this` refers to the event object, rather than the changed element.

Comment: I think I've understood. Sorry for my English.{bool} [default=true]: Show the input global filter in it's input box(es) to false to not display the search text in the box. everything correctly. the problem is when I used the select to look that way when I go to look for the box in the table does not respect me the previous search.